# Android set bitmap to Imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

Hi i have a string in Base64 format. I want to convert it ot a bitmap and then display it to an ImageView. This is the code:

```
ImageView user_image;
Person person_object;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_profile_screen);

    // ImageViews
    user_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImageProfile);

    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    person_object = data.getParcelable("person_object");
    // getPhoto() function returns a Base64 String
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(person_object.getPhoto(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    user_image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
```

This code get the Base64 String successfully and i do not get any error. But It does not display the image.
What can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: pls try add this row : user_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: Does it work with resource images? For example, if you write `iuser_image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)`, will it show anything?

Answer (score 59):

Please try this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(person_object.getPhoto(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
user_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it did not work. I think i convert to bitmap correctly. After i set the bitmap to the view, does it need to be reDrawn to be seen on the screen?

Comment: Did you able to view that image ?

Answer (score 7):

```
    //decode base64 string to image
    imageBytes = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);

  //setImageBitmap is imp
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a library named **Picasso** which can efficiently load images from a URL. It can also load an image from a file.

Examples:

1. Load URL into ImageView without generating a bitmap:

   ```
   Picasso.with(context) // Context
          .load("http://abc.imgur.com/gxsg.png") // URL or file
          .into(imageView); // An ImageView object to show the loaded image
   ```
2. Load URL into ImageView by generating a bitmap:

   ```
   Picasso.with(this)
          .load(artistImageUrl)
          .into(new Target() {
              @Override
              public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                  /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

                  // Set it in the ImageView
                  theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
              }

              @Override
              public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

              }
          });
   ```

There are many more options available in Picasso. [Here is the documentation](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/).

Answer (score 5):

this code works with me

```
 ImageView carView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.car_icon);

                            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(picture, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                            InputStream input=new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
                            Bitmap ext_pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                            carView.setImageBitmap(ext_pic);
```