# How to set an image in an ImageView inside an ExpandableListView group dynamically?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a bitmap on Activity and I want to set that bitmap to an ImageView in a  group in an ExpandableListView.
How can I do this?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));                      (Expandablelistview.imageview).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I need a particular group of my ExpandableListView and then set that ImageView there.
I need this View reference in the Activity.

Comment: Please help soon. what i have to do for this?

Comment: Use yourimageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android set bitmap to Imageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323844/android-set-bitmap-to-imageview)

Comment: how can i get imageview which is set in adapter? because group view of expandablelistview is declare in adapter. Hope u understand what i want

Comment: Every view has their unique id .. find it and setview in it..

Comment: but i have multiple groups in expandablelistview. so how can i get imageview of particular group in activity?

Comment: I have to pick image on click of imageview from gallery and set it to that particular imageview. But the problem is i got bitmap in onActivityResult() in activity. so how can i set expandablelistviews group imageview from there?

Comment: Call the adapter again passing the new imageBitmap

Comment: i posted something man hope it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create array of holders

```
  ArrayList<ViewHolder> holders = new ArrayList<>();


public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

   ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holders.add(holder);
    return null;

}
```

hope you have idea about ViewHolders.. and finally in your activity find the view by  the following code and set imageview

```
holders.get(POSITIONOFLIST).iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I am not getting any ViewHolder in my adapter. Sorry but please help I am new

Comment: now got it. thank u so much. I just test this code and then response. thanks alot

Comment: if it satisfies then you can select this as accepted answer nah?